# bootstrap-sass with ionic 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass

I would have wanted to integrate some of the mixins of bootstrap into ionic 2 but it creates an error that I cannot fix easily.

```
node_modules\bootstrap-sass\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap\_variables.scss
Error: Incompatible units: 'px' and 'rem'.
        on line 214 of node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss
>> $input-height-base:              ($line-height-computed + ($padding-base-verti
   ----------------------------------^
```

From my `app.core.scss` file:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

From my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the `Shared Variables` section in `src/theme/variables.scss`

`$font-size-base: 14px !default;`

Comment: Thanks, this solution is really helpful.